# Calculated Column to get average from values in another table in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, dax

This might be very basic but I am new to PowerBI.

How do I get average of values for unique ID into another table.

For eg. My Table 1 has multiple ID values. I have created another table for unique ID which I am planning to used to join other table.

I want a calculated column in table 2 which will give me average value of respective ID from table 1.

[image]

[image]

How do I get the calculated column like shown below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In stead of creating a new table with the averages per ID and then joining on that, you could also do it directly with a calculated column using the following DAX expression:
 `Average by ID = CALCULATE(AVERAGE('Table 1'[Values]),ALLEXCEPT('Table 1','Table 1'[ID]))`

---

[image]

Not exactly what you asked for, but maybe it's useful anyway.

Comment: This was very helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

How's it going?

The quickest way I can think of doing this would be to use

**SUMMARIZECOLUMNS**

You can accomplish this by creating another table based on your initial fact table like so:

```
Table 2 =
SUMMARIZECOLUMNS ( 'Table 1'[ID], "Avg", AVERAGE ( 'Table 1'[Values] ) )
```

[image]

Once this table has been created, you can create a relationship.

This will work in either SSAS or in PowerBI directly.

Hope this helps!! Have a good one!!

Comment: Will be using the below method but this one works too. Thank you for the information. Unfortunately I cannot mark both as acceptable answers, but this works too.

Comment: Happy to help :)